# Spring load/runs every beans from Configuration class before any bean is used in main?

Tags: java, spring

It's true that Spring load/runs every beans from Configuration class before any bean is used in main?
We got something abstract like:

```
  @Configuration
  public class Config {
     @Bean
     public String aha() {
     System.out.println("ss1s");
     return "sss";
    }
}
```

And in main i got only this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    }
```

I didnt use any beans in main but after run, in console i have "ss1s". That behaviour are correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Spring creates beans eagerly. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Answer (score 2):

It is true. By default Spring eagerly initialize all beans.

To initialize beans lazily you can use the `@Lazy` annotation, like follows

```
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public String aha() {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beans are not lazy by default. However, as far as annotations are concerned it seems like currently, annotations do not support it. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=62931

Spring's next version though seems to have something in store http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SJC-263